# selenium, list index out of range python

Tags: python, selenium

Want to scrape posts count from instagram profile.

However now its giving the error "IndexError: list index out of range" on ubuntu but still works in pycharm. I didnt changed anything in the code.

This is working on pycharm but giving me IndexError on ubuntu. Yesterday it worked for ubuntu.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.instagram.com/system32fanpage/"
browser.get(url)
posts = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[1]/a/span')[0].text
print(posts)
```

result: 8

Webdriver is running headless in ubuntu with xvfb

```
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
```

Comment: use explicit wait to locate element

Comment: @Pratik didnt work. I tried `wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[1]/a/span"))).text` and got TimeoutException and time.sleep

Comment: share your html code so that I can get you a new xpath

Comment: this page https://www.instagram.com/system32fanpage/

Answer (score 0):

Give it some time to load the page before parsing.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.instagram.com/system32fanpage/"
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
posts = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[1]/a/span')[0].text
print(posts)
```

Comment: But this does not guarantee that data is available after timer has ended.